# How to quickly cd to the correct directory?

Tags: terminal, filesystems

Is there any way to quickly cd to the correct directory? I have a lot of subdirectories for my courses and it ends up taking lots of time to cd to get to the correct directory. Especially if I forget the name of the directory.

Are there any tips as good ways to easily get to the correct directory?

Comment: There are answers, but they are very different, depending on the OS, but I'm not sure what help you can expect if you forget the name.

Comment: Most of the time you can type cd and hit the tab key - sometime more then once to expand and show valid options

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this code in bash for changing my programming directory. I called it cpd and everytime I can just call it with `cpd py` and it will take the shortest pattern, so in my case it's Python. 
But if you don't know whole or part of the name, it will be useless.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/Programing
cd "$(find -type d | grep -i "$(echo "${*:1}" | sed 's/ /.*/g')" | awk '{print length($0) " " $0; }' | sort -n | cut -d ' ' -f2- | head -n 1)"
```